# Best way to map hierarchial object to typed iterable tree structure

Tags: typescript

Having a hierarchial data object stored like the following, with nested children,...

```
const data = {
    id: "parent",
    children: {
        child0: {
            id: "child0",
            children: {
              grandchild0: {
                id: "grandchild0",
                children: {}
              }
            }
        },
        child1: {
            id: "child1",
            children: {}
        }
    }
}
```

what would be the simplest way of mapping that data into an recursively iterable tree structure like the following?

```
type Item = {
    id:string,
    children?: Item[],
}
```

Of course I can do it by recursively looping through the data object and build the resulting items - something like

```
function dataToItem(data: any):Item {
    let item:Item = { id: '', children: [] }
    const keys = Object.keys(data);
    for (const key of keys) {
        const value = data[key];
        switch (key) {
            case 'id':
                item.id = value;
                break;
            case 'children':
                item.children = [];
                const children = Object.values(value);
                for (const child of children) {
                    const childItem = dataToItem(child);
                    item.children.push(childItem);
                }
        }
    }
    return item;
}
const item:Item = dataToItem(data);
console.log(item);
```

...but maybe there is a cleaner and simpler way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive data means recursive procedure -

```js
const f = ({ id, children = {} }) =>
  ({ id, children: Object.values(children).map(f) })

const data = {
    id: "parent",
    children: {
        child0: {
            id: "child0",
            children: {
              grandchild0: {
                id: "grandchild0",
                children: {}
              }
            }
        },
        child1: {
            id: "child1",
            children: {}
        }
    }
}

console.log(f(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
{
  "id": "parent",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "child0",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "grandchild0",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "child1",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mulan! Cleaner and simpler! :-)